# CKEditor5 not uploading images in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, multer, ckeditor5

I am trying to integrate CKEditor 5, but I am not winning when it comes to image uploads.

My ejs template looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CKEditor Integration</title>
    <script src="/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="editor"></textarea>

    <script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
                ckfinder: {
                    uploadUrl: '/upload-image-endpoint',
                }
            })
            .then(editor => {
                console.log('Editor was initialized', editor);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error during initialization', error);
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I create a POST request to handle `uploadUrl` and it looks like this:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/')
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9);
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix + path.extname(file.originalname))
}
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/upload-image-endpoint', upload.single('editor'), (req, res) => {
if (!req.file) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'No file uploaded' });
}

const imageUrl = '/uploads/' + req.file.filename;

res.json({ url: imageUrl });
});
```

Whenever I can initially see the image after choosing it from my device, but an alert pops up saying that the image could not be uploaded.

The node.js console throws an error related to multer:

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (/path/to/project/node_modules/multer/index.js:40:19)
    at Multipart.<anonymous> (/path/to/project/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:107:7)
    at Multipart.emit (node:project:514:28)
```

How do I solve this issue and successfully upload files when using the CKEditor?